# PHP SOAP-ERROR: SoapFault Could not connect to host

Tags: php, laravel, soap, wsdl

I'm having a problem with SoapClient (PHP) to connect to host.

With https://ws.ocasa.com/testecommerce/service.asmx?wsdl
I don't know why, I'm having this response:

```
SoapFault Could not connect to host
```

I'm using laravel, and my code is:

```
$auth = new \stdClass();
$auth->UserName = 'xxxxx';
$auth->PassWord = 'xxxxx';
$location = 'https://ws.ocasa.com/testecommerce/service.asmx';
$uri = 'https://ws.ocasa.com/testecommerce/service.asmx?WSDL';

    $this->client = new \SoapClient(null,
        [
            'location'=>$location,
            'uri'=>$uri
        ]);
    $soap_header = new \SoapHeader('http://tempuri.org/','SecurityAccess',$auth,false);
    $this->client->__setSoapHeaders($soap_header);
$this->client->__soapCall("GenerarRetiros", array([]));
```

I tried this WSDL on SoapUI and it works perfect. So it doesn't seem to be the WSDL. But in the code if I replace that WSDL for the one that is below, the error goes away, so I don't know where is the problem, in the code or in the wsdl.

https://id3check.gb.co.uk/gbportalinternational/aspx/id3check_1b.asmx?WSDL

Thank you